# VB.NET Trigger method from within a generic-list property when values change by using Add/Addrange/Remove, etc

Tags: vb.net, events, properties, generic-list

How to call a method from within a property which is declared as a `List(Of T)`, when new values were added into Property?

In my example you see a class called `Something`, another class called `MyClass` with a `Property Things As List(Of Something)`, and my main form where a new instance of `MyClass`is made, then some values has been added into its' `Things` Property by using the `Add` (or `AddRange`) method of generic lists.

**My question:** how to trigger `DoSomeAction()` method every time `Things` property values change (added or removed by using Add, Addrange, Remove, etc. methods)?

```
Public Partial Class MainForm ' System.Windows.Forms.Form
   Dim newMyClass As New MyClass
   newMyClass.Things.Add(New Something())
   newMyClass.Things.AddRange(New Something() {New Something(), New Something()})
End Class

Public Class MyClass
   Private thingsValue As List(Of Something)
   '
   Public Property Things() As List(Of Something)
      Set(value As List(Of Something))
         thingsValue = value
         DoSomeAction()
      End Set
      Get
         Return thingsValue
      End Get
   End Property
   '
   Private Sub DoSomeAction()
      '[inside method DoSomeAction()]
   End Sub
   '
   Public Sub New()
      thingsValue = New List(Of Something)
   End Sub
End Class

Public Class Something
   '[inside class Something]
End Class
```

Comment: rather than exposing the collection itself, implement Add, AddRange etc methods in which your code adds the items then DoesSomeThing()

Comment: BindingList<T> might be a better choice.  It has a ListChanged event, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Because I had already tried `Private WithEvents thingsValue As List(Of Something)' (intuitively) and I saw there were no events. I'll try BindingList.

Comment: I'd tend to go with `ObservableCollection(Of T)`.